# How do I use Gently to stub a method of an object that is not immediately exposed by a module?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, stubbing

I'm using the [AWS SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js) for NodeJS.

I've got a module (`moduleFoo`) set up like this:

```
if (global.GENTLY) { require = GENTLY.hijack(require); }

var aws = require("aws-sdk"),
    ec2;

exports.initEC2Client = function () {
    ec2 = new aws.EC2();
};

exports.doSomething = function () {
    var params;

    // params gets populated here...

    ec2.Client.describeInstances(params, function (err, data) {
        // logic!
    }
}
```

I'm trying to stub out the `describeInstances` method.

I know I can stub the `EC2` class by doing:

```
gently.stub("aws-sdk", "EC2");
```

and I can create a fake instance of that by stubbing its constructor, as per the [Gently docs](https://github.com/felixge/node-gently#gentlystublocation-exportsname):

```
var ec2Stub = gently.stub("aws-sdk", "EC2"),
    ec2;

gently.expect(ec2Stub, "new", function () {
    ec2 = this;
});

moduleFoo.initEC2Client();
```

At this point I get stuck. What I need to do is to stub out a method of an object belonging to `ec2`. Is there a way to approach this using Gently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the answer after having typed out the entire question, just before pressing submit.

I solved it by initialising `Client` as an empty object and then stubbing the `describeInstances` method on it:

```
var ec2Stub = gently.stub("aws-sdk", "EC2"),
    ec2;

gently.expect(ec2Stub, "new", function () {
    ec2 = this;
});

moduleFoo.initEC2Client();

ec2.Client = {};

gently.expect(ec2.Client, "describeInstances", function (params, callback) {
    // assert `params` is populated ok
    callback();
})

moduleFoo.doSomething();

gently.verify(); // throws no error
```